# No context in list event receivers

Tags: 2007, event-receivers

I am dependent on an HttpContext within a utility class to update cache items but for some reason this always returns a NULL context.

It would seem that an HttpContext cannot be inferred from within a receiver or is there something I might be missing?

```
override void ItemUpdates(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    SPUtilitities.CacheActions(ActionType.Update, properities.ListName);
}
```

I get a null reference exception within CacheActions(ActionType, string):

```
void CacheActions(ActionType type, string name)
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current; // null reference exception here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2007,

-ed events run asynchronously, so no, you won't have a HttpContext available to you.

-ing events run synchronously, so you *might* have one.

In addition, because an item can be updated from the API that is not part of a web request, you shouldn't rely on having a HttpContext within an event receiver.

Maybe test for a HttpContext first.

Comment: Hi Paul, so you're saying instead of trying to update the cache in -ed events, I just update them in -ing events?

Comment: Pretty much... but I'd also wrap the call to CacheActions in an if(HttpContext.Current!=null) just incase the item is being updated by something other than a user (eg workflow)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is take a copy of the HttpContext.Current in the contructor for your event handler, and then use it in the event methods themselves:

```
public class MyHandler : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    System.Web.HttpContext _context = null;
    public MyHandler()
    {
        _context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    }

    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
        //Use Context Here
   }
```

It's not pretty, but it does work. I would suggest using with caution.

Comment: Always null in SP2010. Is there anything what I'm doing wrong or have I bad setting? I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 and deploy as Sandboxed solution.